# Gimp Script-Fu cond none of the conditions execute

Tags: gimp, script-fu

I am trying to set up a conditional statement in a Gimp Script-Fu script, and nothing appears to be executing.

```
(gimp-message "before cond")
(cond
    [#t (gimp-message "I should see this")]
    [else (gimp-message "I shouldn't see this")]
)
(gimp-message "after cond")
```

The output I'm getting is the following

```
script-fu.exe-Warning: before cond

script-fu.exe-Warning: after cond
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why are none of my gimp-messages showing up in the `cond` statement?

Comment: Do you know that you can write the script in Python, which is somewhat more programmer-friendly?

Comment: I am aware of that, but for now this is modifying an existing script-fu program. I've also heard that if you want to run the script purely from the console with no gui interaction you at least need a wrapper written in script-fu right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got my syntax for `cond` from racket documentation since there isn't a lot of documentation for TinyScheme or more specifically Script-Fu

I found that the syntax recognized by Gimp is basically the same thing, but replacing the brackets [] with parentheses ()

```
(gimp-message "before cond")
(cond
    (#t (gimp-message "I should see this"))
    (else (gimp-message "I shouldn't see this"))
)
(gimp-message "after cond")
```

After replacing the brackets I got my expected output. It's frustrating that there was no error to say that the brackets were unexpected.